# PS3 power problem

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, hardware

My PS3 cut out while playing black ops 2. The system clicked and turned off, instantly, no red standby light, no response to the power button. I flipped off the power switch in the back, unplugged everything, and checked to see if it needed to be cleared of dust (it didn't). I plugged it back in, flipped power switch on in the back, red standby light turned on, but when I touched the power button, the green light turned on for an instant, the fan started, but then the system clicked off again, same as before. Is there an internal electric breaker in the ps3 i need to reset? Anyone have a similar issue? Or have a solution?

Comment: I've had some issues with my PS3 locking up and occasionally shutting down on its own.  I eventually determined it to be a cooling issue and moved the PS3 to another location with better air flow.

Comment: A device that suddenly shuts down when under load sounds like a cooling issue. Wait for the PS3 to cool down a bit, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Mine did the same thing. It was a cooling issue. I ended up buying one of those fans they use for laptops. Works great. :)